# How do I get iCal push notifications working?

Tags: ical, apns

If I update an event on my iPhone 3GS running iOS 4.3.3, it is updated correctly on the MobileMe calendar web site, but not on iCal – I have to refresh the latter manually. I took a look at my system log, and there are entries like this:

> Sep 23 10:40:59 Musa applepushserviced[147]: : Stream error occurred for : Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=2 UserInfo=0x10012d5e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)"

Could this be responsible? If so, what is the solution?

Comment: Are you still having this issue? What version of OSX are you running.  Also, have you since updated to 5.1.1?  Works great on my 3GS.

Answer (score 1):

MobileMe was [discontinued on June 30, 2012](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MobileMe). Your phone isn't able to sync because the sync servers are no longer available. If you want to sync calendars with an iOS 4 device, you might have to use a Google account and IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to locate any documentation on the returned error. My best advice is to [submit this as a bug report to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com). If they haven't heard of it before, their engineers will get back to you for some more information, and may even offer the solution.